# How to represent a single tree using data from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, database, structure, hierarchy

I have multiple entities which need to be used in a hierarchy. The following applies as an example:

There are a number of Customers
Each customer has a number of Products

I would like to represent these in two seperate tables (Customers, Products) with a reference from Models
to the Makes. That's simple enough, here's the hard part. I need to represent these entities
in different parts of a hierarchical tree like the following (Where certain parts are repeated nodes):

```
New Products
 └ Product 1
   └ Pictures
   └ Prices
 └ Product 2
   └ Pictures
   └ Prices
 └ Product 3
   └ Pictures
   └ Prices
Customers
 └ Customer 1
 └ Customer 2
 └ Customer 3
```

I hope you get the idea. I need to maintain the relationship between customers and products but I need
to represent them as nodes in a tree. Some nodes (like the products above) will have a list composite of
nodes as children. Every single leaf node will need data to be stored against it within a database.

I have thought about representing everything in a nodes table, and having a nodes_assoc table. This
way I can associate a group of nodes to any number of parents. However, I don't really like the idea of 
then applying the customer / product relationship in this table, I feel they are obviously significant enough
to reside in their own table.

To Recap:

Multiple Customers each having multiple Products
Each Customer / Product to be represented as a node (in multiple locations) in an hierarchical tree
Each group of nodes (all products) may have a children group of nodes.
Each leaf node needs to have data stored against it (Maybe just a unique id for that node association)

Hope you can help,

Thanks